# Ignore duplicate entries in MySQL select using DISTINCT keyword

Tags: mysql

I have these values in a table called advertisements:

```
id         sitecatid      locationid
1             12            3
2             12            6
3             12            8
4             12            8 
5             12            8 
6             10            18 
7             13            20
8             14            21
```

I want to return the results like this:

```
sitecatid      locationid
    12            3
    10            6
    13            8
    14            18
                  20
                  21
```

Basically I only want the first instance of any record with a unique sitecatid
and locationid.

**UPDATE:**

I tried this query But the result not correct:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT sitecatid, locationid 
    FROM advertisements 
    WHERE MATCH (sitetitle,sitedescription) 
AGAINST ('$q' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND status='approved'
```

result for The above query:

```
sitecatid      locationid
    12            3
    12            6
    12            8
    10            18
    14            20
    13            21
```

**UPDATE:**

i can use tow query One for `sitecatid` and secend for `locationid` like:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT sitecatid
        FROM advertisements 
        WHERE MATCH (sitetitle,sitedescription) 
    AGAINST ('$q' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND status='approved'
```

AND

```
 SELECT DISTINCT  locationid 
        FROM advertisements 
        WHERE MATCH (sitetitle,sitedescription) 
    AGAINST ('$q' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND status='approved'
```

but i want to use one query For these two

Comment: i dont get your sorting pattern at all

Comment: this is my query :   SELECT * 
    FROM advertisements 
    WHERE MATCH (sitetitle,sitedescription) 
AGAINST ('$q' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND status='approved'

Comment: I think it is not possible because `row 6` of given table contains only staticatid `10` and locationid `18` but your asking to show the value  sitecatid `10` of `row 6` and loctionid  `6` of `row 2` in a single `row`(i.e) you are asking to show two different row values in a single row

Comment: Srini: i want to get all records and I only want the first instance of any record with a unique sitecatid
and locationid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I see to achieve this is to retrieve the data in one column, not two, given the fact that you are trying to get values from different records in a row, which I believe is not possible.

```
SELECT 'SITECATID' UNION
SELECT DISTINCT sitecatid
    FROM advertisements 
    WHERE MATCH (sitetitle,sitedescription) 
    AGAINST ('$q' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND status='approved' UNION
SELECT 'LOCATIONID' UNION
SELECT DISTINCT  locationid 
    FROM advertisements 
    WHERE MATCH (sitetitle,sitedescription) 
    AGAINST ('$q' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND status='approved';
```

Comment: @ebrahimbabavand, could you elaborate? I just unioned your queries and put a literal header to each one of them.

Comment: this is working now im using  this query 


`$get = "SELECT *,sitecatid, COUNT(*) as count  FROM advertisements WHERE MATCH (sitetitle,sitedescription) AGAINST ('$q' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND status='approved' GROUP BY sitecatid ";`




    ` $get = "SELECT *,locationid, COUNT(*) as count  FROM advertisements WHERE MATCH (sitetitle,sitedescription) AGAINST ('$q' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND status='approved' GROUP BY locationid ";`